# After passing a value as a parameter I get [object Object],[object Object]

Tags: arrays, typescript, parameters, console.log

Problem: I would like pass an object Array (which I received from Local-storage) as a parameter to _filter() and use it.

Expected: It will show the same value in _filter() after I passed it as a parameter.

Actual result: I get value:  [object Object],[object Object]

I tried: tempTodos: Todo[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfly(todos)); // At _filter() and it shows again [object Object],[object Object]
I also tried console.log(JSON.parse(todo)) // at _filter()  and it shows the array but as a string.

todo-service code Exmple Where I pass a a correct object array value to _filter():

```
let todos: Todo[] = utilService.load(this.KEY);
if (!todos.length) {
  this._todos$.next(TODOS);
  utilService.save(this.KEY, todos);// Set storage to []
}
if (filterBy && filterBy.term || filterBy.category) {
  todos = this._filter(todos, filterBy.term, filterBy.category);
}
```

todo-service _filter() where I print inside  [object Object],[object Object]

```
  private _filter(todos: Todo[], term: string, category: string) {
term = term.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return todos.filter(todo => {
  if (category) {
    todo.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(term) &&
      todo.category === category;
  }
  else{
    todo.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(term);
  }
}
)
```

}

Comment: your filter() call  returns void and not a boolean (you have no explicit return)

Comment: Thank you @Matthieu Reigler , That's another important thing that I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to change the last problematic console.log to one without interpulation. I don't know how but it works!

Thanks to Roy Azami.